# problema em C com resto da divisão

Tags: c, array, matriz, matemática

Desenvolver um programa que efetue a leitura de dez elementos de uma matriz A tipo vetor. Construir uma matriz B de mesmo tipo, observando a seguinte lei de formação: se o valor do índice for par, o valor deverá ser multiplicado por 5, sendo ímpar, deverá ser somado com 5. Ao final mostrar o conteúdo da matriz A e B.

Quando eu vou compilar o programa mostra o seguinte erro.

> 2417  19  C:\Users\User\Documents\DEV C++\aula03.cpp  [Error] expected
>   primary-expression before ';' token

Ele destaca a linha "resp = indice %;", como sendo a linha com erro.
Desde já sou grato pela ajuda de vocês.

```
    int matriza[10];
    int matrizB[10];
    int indice;
    int resp;

    for( indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++ )
     {
     printf("digite um valor numerico inteiro: ");
     scanf ("%d", &matriza[indice]);
     }

    for(indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++)
     {
     resp = indice %;
     if (resp == 0)
     matrizB[indice] = matriza[indice] * 5;
     else
     matrizB[indice] = matriza[indice] + 5;
     }

    for(indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++)
     printf ("\nConteudo da matriz a indice %d = %d", indice,           matriza[indice]);

    for(indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++)
     printf ("\nConteudo da matriz B indice %d = %d", indice, matrizB[indice]);
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Só faltou você fazer a divisão por 2 para saber se é par ou não. Você não pode parar a expressão matemática no meio.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int matriza[10];
    int matrizB[10];
    int indice;
    for (indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++) {
        printf("digite um valor numerico inteiro: ");
       scanf ("%d", &matriza[indice]);
     }
    for (indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++) {
        if (indice % 2 == 0) matrizB[indice] = matriza[indice] * 5;
        else matrizB[indice] = matriza[indice] + 5;
    }
    for (indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++) printf ("\nConteudo da matriz a indice %d = %d", indice, matriza[indice]);
    for (indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++) printf ("\nConteudo da matriz B indice %d = %d", indice, matrizB[indice]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/tcnUB1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yssefgtc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/ModSyntax.c).

Não verifiquei se o resto da lógica está certa, só resolvi o problema da pergunta. nem tão pouco simplifiquei e organizei melhor o código. O código está bem ruim de ler. tente aprender fazer as coisas de forma mais organizada e evitará erros bobos assim.

Comment: Esse código não foi feito por mim, eu copiei e colei aqui, ele é um dos exercícios da apostila, fiz ele no DevC++, e ele apresentou esse erro.

Comment: Não tente aprender com um material tão ruim. Inclusive um que deve ter indicado o uso do Dev-C++ como algo bom pra se trabalhar :)

Comment: @user8470 você devia procurar outras fontes para aprender como já foi mencionado e também trocava de IDE.

Answer (score 1):

```
resp = indice %;
```

A linha não é válida, a expressão está incompleta, falta um argumento. Pelo enunciado da questão sugiro que seja o número 2 pois existe a necessidade de descobrir se o número é par ou não. O erro postado pode ser corrigido assim.

```
resp = indice % 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

O operador `%` lhe fornece o resto da divisão de um número (o dividendo) por outro número (o divisor). Logo, você precisa fornecer os dois números para o operador. Alguns exemplos:

```
5 % 2 = 1
6 % 4 = 2
9 % 3 = 0
```

O erro ocorreu devido ao fato de você ter fornecido apenas o dividendo para o operador. Ficou faltando fornecer o divisor. Seria algo como `5 %`, o que não faz sentido para o compilador.

Para corrigir o erro, basta fornecer o divisor para o operador `%`:

```
resp = indice % 2;
```

Espero ter esclarecido sua dúvida e ter lhe ajudado a corrigir o erro.